# creating a model class with an image

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios

Is there an efficient way to load an image into a model class?  The model is something like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface ProjectData : NSObject {

NSString *titleText;
UIImage *photo;
NSString *descriptionText;

}

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *titleText;
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIImage *photo;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *descriptionText;
@end
```

Project is something like a catalog.

I have been loading the strings from webserver using XML from mySQL database.  Images are on database. Not quite sure how to proceed with image loading into ProjectData class. NSMutableData? or is there an easier way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` or `UIImagePNGRepresentation` when to encode (writing) your objects. And just use `[UIImage imageWithData:data]` when decoding (reading).

*Note: If you will be reading and writing back objects often you should use the PNG version. Jpeg will make the image worse and worse*

*Note 2: Oh yes, if the images are large you shouldn't store them in your db but rather on disk and just store a reference in the db*

Answer (score 0):

Instead of subclassing `NSObject`, you could subclass `UIImageView`.